# content ripping from stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service, content-reuse

Just found this by google:
http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=197396

which is a copy of
[How do I enable tcpwrapper (hosts.deny) filter in mysqld / mariadb](https://serverfault.com/questions/513760/how-do-i-enable-tcpwrapper-hosts-deny-filter-in-mysqld-mariadb)

Is it allowed?

Comment: @Doorknob, Eugene - the site seems to follow the attribution rules though, so it seems to be legal (context: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)

Comment: @Pekka웃 No it doesn't. There are no links back the the user who asked the question.

Comment: @Doorknob there is, underneath the title ("Author: ...")

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, didn't notice that. Okay then